# How to correctly write declarations of extern arrays in C's header files?

Tags: c++, arrays, extern

First of all, let me confess that pointer-to-an-array always gets me confused. Hence, I am asking this question.

Suppose I want to share a global array of data across my program, for example:

```
static const char * EnumStrings_WIP_Selection_Box[] = { "Rectangular", "Siemens Gauss", "My_Gauss", "Planck-Taper", "Invalid"};
```

When I try to declare corresponding “extern” command

```
extern static const char * EnumStrings_WIP_Selection_Box[];
```

or

```
extern static const char * EnumStrings_WIP_Selection_Box[5];
```

I get the following error

```
error C2159: more than one storage class specified
```

Also, can someone also tell me the different between these?

```
Foo *array[10];
Foo (*array1)[10];
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't make a `static` variable accessible in other [translation units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`extern` and `static` are both storage classes, and are mutually exclusive.

Don't specify them together.  You want:

```
extern const char * EnumStrings_WIP_Selection_Box[];
```

The `static` conflicts with the `extern`.

Comment: And don't declare the source array as `static` either.

Comment: `const` doesn't specify linkage.

Comment: @Mgetz `extern const` is a constant with external linkage. `static const` and `const` both have internal linkage.

Comment: No, `const` is part of the type, it does not specify linkage.  It just so happens that `const` variables at file scope have internal linkage.

Comment: Also, this is not a constant variable, the same way `char * Array[]` would not be a constant. You need `[const] char *const Array[]` for that.

Answer (score 3):

I've assumed you want you array to be "totally" constant, as many people aren't aware of the two-consts on a pointer. This means not only can the text pointed to by the array not change, the pointers in the array also cannot be changed to point to new text.

You should make sure the data in your array is defined in a source file, or you risk a copy of the data in memory for every source file that includes the header.

Header file

```
extern const char *const MyText[];
```

Source file

```
extern const char *const MyText[] = { "Hello", "There"; };
```

Alternatively, the C++ approach

Header file

```
extern const std::vector<std::string> MyText;
```

Source file

```
extern const std::vector<std::string> MyText = { "Hello", "There"; };
```

To force it all in one file (not recommended in a header file)

```
const char *const MyText[] = { "Hello", "There"; };
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

.cpp file:

```
/* not static */
const char * EnumStrings_WIP_Selection_Box[] = { "Rectangular",
    "Siemens Gauss", "My_Gauss", "Planck-Taper", "Invalid"};
```

.h[pp] file:

```
extern const char * EnumStrings_WIP_Selection_Box[];
```

That said, for the sake of future maintainers, please consider defining your access in terms of methods, not exposed pointers (i.e. consider adding a `char const * const GetWipSelectionByIndex(const std::size_t index)` to your public API, instead of exposing an array).